# Passing pointers to different variable types to a function and reuse them later for assignmet

Tags: c++, variables, templates, pointers, code-reuse

In a GUI based project I need Page1 to mark a variable *to be changed* and call Page2, Page2 reads user's input and updates the marked variable with the new value.
The variable type is always different and all the variables are held by an external linked library.

**How to achieve that without creating fname_uint8, fname_uint16, fname_giventype variants for markers and setters?**

*This example sums up the scenario:*

There is the `VarHolder` class that holds a lot of structs with a lot of variables, e.g.:

```
class VarHolder 
{
public:
    typedef struct {
        int8_t var1;
        int16_t var2;
        int32_t var3;
        char str1[40];
        float var4;
    } struct1_t;
    /* ...continues... */

struct1_t struct1;
}
```

Now the class `FirstStage` wants to mark one variable for change, and calls a member of the `committer_instance` instance of the class `Committer`

```
class FirstStage 
{
    /* ... */
    void doFirstStage(void)
    {
        /* Globally defined committer instance */
        g_committer_instance->mark_var_change(&varholder_instance->struct1.var1);
    }
}
```

`Committer::mark_var_change(T*)` is defined as follows:

```
template <typename T>
void Committer::mark_var_change(T *var)
{
    /* Store a pointer to the variable */
    /* SAVE SOMEWHERE PRESERVING TYPE */ = var;
}
```

A member of `SecondStage`, finally, wants to use a now available value to update the variable marked for change through the same `g_committer_instance`, like this:

```
class SecondStage
{
    /* ... */
    template <typename T>
    void doSecondStage(T new_value)
    {
        g_committer_instance->commit_change(new_value);
    }
}
```

where `Committer::commit_change(T)` is defined as follows:

```
template <typename T>
void Committer::commit_change(T new_value)
{
    /* Dereferencing the previously stored pointer */
    *(/*WHATEVER I STORED BEFORE*/) = new_value;
}
```

Of course what I am not able to do is realize a type-indipendent "marker and retriever" that can seamlessy update variable based upon their address.
Any suggestion is very much appreciated.

MCVE

```
### varholder.h
#include <stdint.h>
class VarHolder
{
public:
VarHolder() {}
virtual ~VarHolder() {}
typedef struct 
{
int8_t var1;
uint8_t var2;
int64_t var3;
char str1[40];
} struct1_t;

struct1_t struct1;
}

### firststage.h
#include global.h

class FirstStage 
{    
public:
    FirstStage() {}
    ~FirstStage() {}

    void doFirstStage(void)
    {
        /* Globally defined committer instance */
        g_committer_instance->mark_var_change(&varholder_instance->struct1.var1);
    }
}

### secondstage.h
#include global.h

class SecondStage
{
    public:
    SecondStage() {}
    ~SecondStage() {}
    template <typename T>
    void doSecondStage(T new_value)
    {
        g_committer_instance->commit_change(new_value);
    }
}
### committer.h
#include global.h

class Committer
{
    public:
    Committer() {}
    ~Committer() {}
template <typename T>
void Committer::mark_var_change(T *var)
{
    /* Store a pointer to the variable */
    /* SAVE SOMEWHERE PRESERVING TYPE */ = var;
}

template <typename T>
void Committer::commit_change(T new_value)
{
    /* Dereferencing the previously stored pointer */
    *(/*WHATEVER I STORED BEFORE*/) = new_value;
}
}


### global.h

#include varholder.h
#include committer.h

extern Committer *g_committer_instance;
extern VarHolder *varholder_instance;

### main.cpp

#include global.h
#include varholder.h
#include firststage.h
#include secondstage.h


Committer *g_committer_instance;
VarHolder *varholder_instance;

int main() 
{
g_committer_instance = new Committer();
varholder_instance = new VarHolder();
FirstStage *fstage = new FirstStage();
SecondStage *sstage = new SecondStage();

int8_t var_new = 100;

/* First stage */
fstage->doFirstStage();
/* Second stage */
sstage->doSecondStage(var_new);

return 0;
}
```

Comment: You may look at `boost::any`.

Comment: Please create an [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) that describes your problem.

Comment: Is there only one variable per type in `struct1_t`? If so, why not use a union? Also, what will be the behaviour if the type of `new_value` is not convertible to `varholder_instance->struct1.var1`

Comment: @Component10 nope, any number per type. the user of the facility has to check convertibility, anyway casting is done at compile time.

Comment: @TobiMcNamobi I added a MCVE as requested

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may use `void*` without (unsafe) or with `typeid`:

```
class Committer
{
public: 

    template <typename T>
    void mark_var_change(T *var)
    {
        mPointer = var;
        mTypeInfo = &typeid(T*);
    }

    template <typename T>
    void commit_change(T new_value)
    {
        if (*mTypeInfo != typeid(T*)) {
            throw std::runtime_error("Bad type");
        }
        if (mPointer == nullptr) {
            throw std::runtime_error("nullptr was stocked");
        }
        *reinterpret_cast<T*>(mPointer) = new_value;
    }

private:
    void* mPointer = nullptr;
    const std::type_info* mTypeInfo = nullptr;
};
```

- without typeid [Live example](https://ideone.com/gPmN6b)
- with typeid [Live example](https://ideone.com/VaIHQD)

or a safer `boost::any` which manage by itself the type:

```
class Committer
{
public: 

    template <typename T>
    void mark_var_change(T *var)
    {
        mPointer = var;
    }

    template <typename T>
    void commit_change(T new_value)
    {
        T* pointer = boost::any_cast<T*>(mPointer); // throw with bad type
        if (pointer == nullptr) {
            throw std::runtime_error("nullptr was stocked");
        }
        *pointer = new_value;
    }

private:
    boost::any mPointer;
};
```

[Live example](https://ideone.com/fxO35C)

Comment: Already tried the first solution, but even a typo would be fatal in that case, overwriting subsequent parts of the struct (if lucky)...does a non-boost boost::any exist by the way?
As of now boost is a non viable solution...

Comment: @FrancisStraccia: `void*` version modified to use `typeid` to check type.